# Como carregar TableView de forma Dinâmica

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Ola pessoal estou com dificuldade em criar um menu dinamicamente carregando diretamente de uma lista.
Em meu projeto esta da seguinte maneira

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App1.Master"
             Title="Master">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <TableView x:Name="tbMenu">

    </TableView>   

  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

---

```
 tbMenu.Root = new TableRoot
            {
                new TableSection("Menu")
                    {
                        new TextCell
                        {
                            Text = "DESTAQUE",
                            Command = navigateCommad,
                            CommandParameter = typeof(Default)

                        },
                        new TextCell
                        {
                            Text = "ESPORTES",
                            Command = navigateCommad,
                            CommandParameter = typeof(Default)

                        },
                        new TextCell
                        {
                            Text="ENTRETENIMENTO",
                            Command = navigateCommad,
                            CommandParameter = typeof(Default)
                        }

                    }

             };
```

---

Gostaria de preencher a tableview de forma dinâmica vindo diretamente de uma list Categoria tentei com for e foreach mais sem sucesso alguém poderia me dar um help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa setar o Intent do TableView.

```
tbMenu.Intent = TableIntent.Settings; //ou TableIntent.Form
```

Um exemplo bacana (está no site de docs da Xamarin):

```
        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            Content = new TableView {
            Intent = TableIntent.Form,
            Root = new TableRoot ("Table Title") {
                new TableSection ("Section 1 Title") {
                    new TextCell {
                        Text = "TextCell Text",
                        Detail = "TextCell Detail"
                    },
                    new EntryCell {
                        Label = "EntryCell:",
                        Placeholder = "default keyboard",
                        Keyboard = Keyboard.Default
                    }
                },
                new TableSection ("Section 2 Title") {
                    new EntryCell {
                        Label = "Another EntryCell:",
                        Placeholder = "phone keyboard",
                        Keyboard = Keyboard.Telephone
                    },
                    new SwitchCell {
                        Text = "SwitchCell:"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
```